# Could it be that there is a "bug" when inserting a link later on in a question/Answer?

Tags: bug

Atma was wondering, having been goodwilled reproved that he was giving a link double (in some case) and had just observed that such actually happens if you insert a link via the link funktion later on in certain cases. It will simply override an existing or use an existing no. twice.

Maybe useful to give it a check and maybe even an improvement or a notification "don't use link function when insert link late on, but do it in the [[..]] (..) way"